# How i can generate the probabilistic graph for my dataset?

Tags: r, graphs

Im doing my academic project. im having the base paper for reference  the paper is IEEE paper "effective and efficient clustering methods for correlated probabilistic graph". i wish to do this in R tool. in this paper two algorithm are implemented. i like to implement the peedr algorithm in the paper. how can i give the input for that algorithm.? suggest the packgages in R tool
 the paper can be found here
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6570474

Comment: This is probably not suitable as a question as-is. You should indicate what you have tried and what your specific question is about the input format and package you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Søren Højsgaard has many quality resources for graphical models in R. He has a tutorial ["Graphical Models with R"](http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/misc/2012-Oslo-GMwR/GMwR-notes.pdf) and a [list of CRAN packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html).

Additionally, [mclust](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html) is one of the best clustering packages in R.